# SolrCore Initialization Failures

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solr5

I am using Solr-5.0.0 and when i am trying to create  a core in that i am getting the following error in logging.

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
```

This is the exception in the logging

```
4/17/2015, 3:49:23 PM
ERROR
SolrCore
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1984)
    at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$5.call(SolrCore.java:1751)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
4/17/2015, 3:49:23 PM
ERROR
CoreContainer
Error creating core [TEST]: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:885)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:652)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:518)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:620)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:868)
```

My actual data is in mongoDB.

My solrconfig.xml file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<config>

  <luceneMatchVersion>5.0.0</luceneMatchVersion>


  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/solr-mongo-importer-1.0.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/mongo-java-driver-2.9.0.jar" />


  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>


  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>


  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>


  <indexConfig>

    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>


     <infoStream>true</infoStream>
  </indexConfig>



  <jmx />

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">


    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>


     <autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>


     <autoSoftCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
     </autoSoftCommit>



  </updateHandler>


  <query>

    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>



    <slowQueryThresholdMillis>-1</slowQueryThresholdMillis>



    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>

    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>

    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>


    <cache name="perSegFilter"
      class="solr.search.LRUCache"
      size="10"
      initialSize="0"
      autowarmCount="10"
      regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />


    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>


   <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>


   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>

    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">

      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </listener>


    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>


    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>

  </query>



  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >

    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>


    <httpCaching never304="true" />

  </requestDispatcher>



    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">  
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">dealdeals-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
     </lst>

    </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>



  <requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
      <str name="wt">xsort</str>
      <str name="distrib">false</str>
    </lst>

    <arr name="components">
      <str>query</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>



  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
       <str name="wt">velocity</str>
       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
          title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
       </str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>

       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
         title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat,title,description,keywords,author,resourcename</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

       <!-- Faceting defaults -->
       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <str name="facet.missing">true</str>
       <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
       <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.field">content_type</str>
       <str name="facet.field">author_s</str>
       <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
       <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
       <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
       <str name="facet.range">price</str>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
       <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
       <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>

       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">content features title name</str>
       <str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
       <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b&gt;</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
       <str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.snippets">3</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.fragsize">200</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.alternateField">content</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">750</str>

       <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
       <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>           
     </lst>

     <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!--<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
  </requestHandler>-->
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <initParams path="/update/json/docs">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!--this ensures that the entire json doc will be stored verbatim into one field-->
      <str name="srcField">_src_</str>

      <str name="mapUniqueKeyOnly">true</str>
    </lst>

  </initParams>



  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>


      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />

  <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
                  class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />

  <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
     <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>


    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">text</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>

    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>


  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">

      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent" 
                   enable="${solr.suggester.enabled:false}"     >
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">cat</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" enable="${solr.suggester.enabled:false}" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>




  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>


  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="clustering"
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">lingo</str>


      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>

      <str name="carrot.resourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>
    </lst>

    <!-- An example definition for the STC clustering algorithm. -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>

    <!-- An example definition for the bisecting kmeans clustering algorithm. -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">kmeans</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans.BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
                  startup="lazy"
                  enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                  class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
      <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
      <!-- Field name with the logical "title" of a each document (optional) -->
      <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
      <!-- Field name with the logical "URL" of a each document (optional) -->
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>
      <!-- Field name with the logical "content" of a each document (optional) -->
      <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
      <!-- Apply highlighter to the title/ content and use this for clustering. -->
      <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
      <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
      <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
      <!-- produce sub clusters -->
      <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>

      <!-- Configure the remaining request handler parameters. -->
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
        text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
      </str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>


      <fragmenter name="regex" 
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html" 
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html" 
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">

      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>


  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">

    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!--
     Custom response writers can be declared as needed...
    -->
    <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy">
      <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
    </queryResponseWriter>


  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>


  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

Comment: @cheffe have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Your core config comes from a different version of Solr.

So a few solutions:

- re-create config files from scratch
- get a different version
- get a Solr guru to pinpoint where the issue is :)

Comment: It was because of version change in for me

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do not have duplicated .jars. For me it was duplicated jar in core's lib folder. It started throwing null pointers after migrating to SOLR 5

Answer (score 0):

I copied a solr 5.0.0 core on windows 8.1 to a solr 5.2.1 installation on ubuntu 14.04. First, solr service didn't even start. Then I moved the core to another location and added it by hand (i.e. created directories, tried to add a core from webapp, copied missing files, tried to add a core from webapp, etc.).
At some time I came to that exception.

The problem was, that I had solr-dataimporthandler-5.0.0.jar and solr-dataimporthandler-extras-5.0.0.jar in the lib directory of my core. So I deleted those and copied solr-dataimporthandler-5.2.1 and solr-dataimporthandler-extras-5.2.1 from /opt/solr/dist to my core's lib directory and I had no more exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SolrCore Initialization Failures
> ```

I noticed that the data directory was not pointing to the correct data directory so I had to change it from `<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>` to  `<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:/var/solr/data}</dataDir>` in the file

`/var/solr/data/ckan/conf/solrconfig.xml`

On going through the solrconfig.xml, I noted that extra comments were added eg  `<!--<!--<!--` and and `-->-->-->` respectively on some lines of code, this was also causing an issue for ckan to initiate.

```
<!--<!--<!-- <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory"> -->-->-->
```

If that is the case, then comment it correctly for example;

```
<!-- <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
        <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
      </lst>
    </processor>
  -->
```

and make sure that everything else is well commented as I found other lines of code that were not commented well, ensure to comment them correctly.

Finally,

**restart solr**

```
/etc/init.d/solr restart
```

or

```
sudo service solr restart
```

and then, check to see that everything works fine and don't forget to look at the logging for any other issues.

http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ckan

Happy debugging !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same strange error message in my logs WebUI of Solr:

> SolrCore Initialization Failures gettingstarted: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Please check your logs for more information

It did happen after I switched to the `Solr` `cloud` mode:

And then I did found out that my `docker-compose volume` still had old data in it so I did search for it via

```
docker volume ls | grep solr
```

and removed it via

```
docker volume rm <name>
```

In my case I also had first to remove the container using it. But then it did not longer show up that error message.